# How do I convert a char pointer to lower case

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character, char-pointer

I'm trying to fix my program...but I don't know how to fix this error "Bus error: 10".

convert to lower case function:

```
void toLowerCase(char* s){
    while(*s){
        if(*s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z'){
            *s = tolower(*s);
            ++s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug to see what is the input of that function when it is called ?

Comment: Your `while` loop will get stuck and run forever as soon as it comes across a character that isn't an uppercase letter! Move the `++s` to ***outside*** the `if` block.

Comment: You're less likely to make that kind of mistake if you use a `for` loop instead of `while`.

Comment: Note that `tolower` also checks that it was passed an uppercase character before converting it, and does not know you already made that check. So you are wasting processor time.

Comment: @Bamar, so we will see that horrible `for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)` in which `strlen` is called again and again??

Comment: Either 1) You don't need the if-statement or 2) you shouldn't call `tolower` but do the conversion yourself.

Comment: @4386427 you *should* use the supplied function: it is safe and portable.

Comment: @WeatherVane sure, sure ... but I guess this is yet another homework and it's like the goal is to write your own conversion...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `for(; *s; ++s) { }` – I cannot understand why people always go over indices when they could do far better with iterators...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I certainly hope not, but `for(; *s; ++s)` would be an improvement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Can I not modify a string literal in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584310/why-can-i-not-modify-a-string-literal-in-c)

Comment: @P__J__ not really :/ but I solved it now

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers guys :D 
that's my code:

```
void toLowerCase(char* s){
    while(*s){
        *s = tolower(*s);
        ++s;
    }
}
```

Now I call the function with:

```
char* arr = "PrOgRaM";
toLowerCase(arr);
```

Comment: Yep, that is a literal string and is unmodifiable (read-only). Any attemp to change a letter to lowercase will cause a seg fault or other type of program abort.

Comment: Instead, use `char arr[] = "PrOgRaM";`

Comment: yeah that's the case...I thinking of duplicating the char array and modify it then. But the Problem is I shouldn't use the function strdup() or any function which allocates memory...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie actually it's undefined behaviour, so it may work on certain platforms.

Answer (score -1):

https://godbolt.org/z/cjf3kS

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *mylower(char *str)
{
    char *bkp = str;
    while(*str = tolower(*str)) str++;
    return bkp;
}


int main()
{
    char str[]="sdfh><:{^$#WGFDS@SDVERTY3453gflsdwjlgkerZXC||A||";

    printf("%s\n", mylower(str));
}
```

Comment: What's the answer in this answer?