# Array and pointer differences

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In a C program, suppose I have a char array and a char pointer.

1.

```
char word[6] = "HELLO";
word[1] = 'A';
```

2.

```
char * word = "HELLO";
word[1] = 'A';
```

Why cant't we update the word using the 2nd method but can with 1st?

Note: Using 2nd method, though the program compiles there is a

> Segmentation fault

error.

Comment: Because in the second example you are trying to modify a "string literal" which is read-only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String literals: pointer vs. char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795850/string-literals-pointer-vs-char-array)

Comment: Please see[Why Can I not modify a string literal in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584310/why-can-i-not-modify-a-string-literal-in-c)

Comment: Closing with another duplicate.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks a lot. Excellent suggestion.