# Why editing a * string in C results in a segmentation fault, but a [] one doesn't?

Tags: c, string

Good day,

I have a function `ft_strupcase` which takes in a `char*`, upper-cases it, and returns the parameter. The issue arose during the testing, namely using the function in a `main`. The following program results in a segmentation fault:

```
    int main()
    {
        char *hey = "hEy";
        printf("%s\n", ft_strupcase(hey));
    }
```

whereas this variation doesn't:

```
    int main()
    {
        char hey[] = "hEy";
        printf("%s\n", ft_strupcase(hey));
    }
```

Isn't `*str` and `str[]` the same? Doesn't `str[i]` = `*(str + i)`? Why do I encounter a segfault then?

Comment: Please see [Why can't I write to a string literal while I *can* write to a string object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718740/why-cant-i-write-to-a-string-literal-while-i-can-write-to-a-string-object)

Comment: Please see [Why can I not modify a string literal in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584310/why-can-i-not-modify-a-string-literal-in-c) and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    char *hey = "hEy";
    printf("%s\n", ft_strupcase(hey));
}
```

In this code, `hey` points to a string literal, which is a constant. Then `ft_strupcase` modifies the thing you pass it a pointer to. So this code attempts to modify a constant.

You can't modify a constant. That's what it means for something to be constant.

```
int main()
{
    char hey[] = "hEy";
    printf("%s\n", ft_strupcase(hey));
}
```

Here, `hey` is an array of characters, initialized from a constant. The array is modifiable since the array entries are not constants.

If you have `int i = 3;`, you can modify `i`, but you can't modify the `3`. The first code tries to modify the thing on the right side of the `=` by passing a function that modifies the thing pointed to a pointer to it. The second code modifies the thing on the left side of the `=`, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: This answer should be made sticky, cos the there are so many beginner irritations, that make the mistake, to assume that initializing a char* with a string is the same as an assignment. So the simple rule is, if you later want to change the string, use an array, otherwise you can use a pointer to the string literal. Ideally make the pointer const.

Comment: @wired there is an old answer. Very frequent dupe. I would not answer it again

Comment: one thing I noticed is that segmentation fault appears only in functions that attempt to modify a string in some way; any other function that just reads from inside works perfectly fine with *-initialized strings. thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: question: had I malloc'd enough memory (4 bytes) for `hey`, then assigned the "hEy" to the pointer, would've the problem be resolved?

Comment: @Mampac It depends what you mean by "then assigned the 'hEy' to the pointer". If you mean `hey = malloc(4); hey  = "hEy";` then no, you just leaked the pointer you `malloc`ed. If you mean `hey = malloc(4); strcpy(hey, "hEy");` then yes, because you *copied* the constant's *value* into something modifiable, then modified the copy.